# How to create a minimum spanning tree with R

Tags: r, tree, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm trying to create a minimum spanning tree with R.
My problem is that I have my distances stored in a txt as follow:

```
PID1  PID2 distance
1      4     0.002
2      5     0.004
3      6     0.003
```

Does exist anyway in which I can use my txt as matrix? I tried to transform it but I couldn't.

Comment: *I tried to transform it but I couldnt.* - what did you try?  `as.matrix()`?

Comment: yes, I did dat=read.table("distances.txt",  dec='.', header=T)
Matrix<- as.matrix(dat)

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't work.  What is the error message?

Comment: I've tried with: mstree <-mst(Matrix) #distmat is a distance matrix
Error en `[<-`(`*tmp*`, j, index.i, value = 139127) : 
  subscript out of bounds

Comment: You don't want a matrix. As a start `mstree(nbw, ini = NULL)` where `nbw` is an object of listw class returned by `nb2listw` function. See `?mstree` for more details.